# Emacs paste into search (C-s) field?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Let's say you are writing code in one of *Emacs* window and then want to search for a string that you have copied manually (<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>) some time before.

The problem is, that by default, when you issue <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> key sequence, *Emacs* pastes the remaining line under a cursor as a search parameter -- but that's not what I want.

My current workaround is to grab a mouse, click on a *Minibuf* then yank, but it's too much time consuming.

Version: *GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.10)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just press Return after C-s and then you can paste the search string:

```
Emacs also has conventional nonincremental search commands, which
require you to type the entire search string before searching begins.

`C-s <RET> STRING <RET>'
     Search for STRING.

`C-r <RET> STRING <RET>'
     Search backward for STRING.

   To start a nonincremental search, first type `C-s <RET>'.  This
enters the minibuffer to read the search string; terminate the string
with <RET>, and then the search takes place.  If the string is not
found, the search command signals an error.
```

Answer (score 4):

The default key to paste into an interactive search is `M-y`.

Answer (score 3):

If you never really use the 'rest of line' behavior, you can just bind C-y to yank and save yourself the 2 extra keystrokes.

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-y" 'isearch-yank-kill)
(define-key isearch-mode-map "\M-y" 'isearch-yank-pop)
```

I'm not sure if these isearch-yank commands are defined in your version of emacs. If not, just replace them with `yank` and `yank-pop`.